# Cannot inherit from event args class: no contructor?

Tags: c#, inheritance, webclient

I'm using `WebClient` in a .NET 4.7.2 WinForms application. I calling the `UploadProgressChanged` event, which receives an `UploadProgressChangedEventArgs` object. I'd like to add a extra property to the event args, so I'm trying to extend `UploadProgressChangedEventArgs` as `UploadProgressChangedExtEventArgs`.

```
    public class UploadProgressChangedExtEventArgs : UploadProgressChangedEventArgs {
        public UploadProgressChangedExtEventArgs() { }
    
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

However, I get the error "CS1729: 'UploadProgressChangedEventArgs' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments."

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.uploadprogresschangedeventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2) (and Object Browser seems to support this) `UploadProgressChangedEventArgs` doesn't have a constructor -- like, at all -- though it's base object `ProgressChangedEventArgs` does. I've tried using `base()` to supply the arguments to the `ProgressChangedEventArgs` constructor, but then I get "does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments" error.

Am I just not able to inherit from `UploadProgressChangedEventArgs` object? Is this a bug in .NET? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: It does have a constructor, [but it's internal](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.WebClient/System/Net/WebClient.cs,2203). The type is effectively sealed: you can't inherit from it

Comment: That's too bad. Guess I'll work around with another custom event handler I call from the UploadProgressChanged event handler.